# How to keep IPFS files alive online forever?

Tags: go-ethereum, ipfs

I'm using IPFS to host a website and I need a way to keep the website files online all the time.

I know that ipfs has a garbage collector that removes the content after 24 hours.

And that if I pin the content with `ipfs pin add <file>` then it's like adding the file again so it's not deleted from the network.

Now my question is **How do I keep my IPFS files online forever?**

Can I create a cron job to keep re-pinning the content every 24 hours? or is there a better way?

Comment: The problem is that I was using other address when doing `ipfs name public <hash>` so yeah. It works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once a piece of content is pinned, it is stored forever on your node until you explicitly unpin it. There is no need to pin a file more than once. If you pin a file, it never gets garbage collected like the files that are not pinned do.

From the [IPFS Pinning Example](https://docs.ipfs.io/guides/examples/pinning/):

> A pinned object cannot be garbage collected, if you dont believe me try this:
>
> ```
> ipfs add foo
> ipfs repo gc
> ipfs cat <foo hash>
> ```

Comment: I did pin the item and it doesn't work, the file still gets removed after a while

Comment: If you need to pin only once, then why keep paying for services like pinnata?

Comment: @PedroD If you don't feel like running/maintaining your own node indefinitely that keeps your content pinned, you'll want to make sure someone else is willing to. A service like Pinata will do that for you.

Comment: I have same issue, all files were pinned and now its not accessable. Stuck on collecting chinks of cat(cid)